# embed portlet in template for liferay

Tags: templates, liferay, portlet, embedding

I am using liferay 6.1 CE (Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.1.1 CE GA2 (Paton / Build 6101 / July 31, 2012))

When I want to embed for example navigation portlet in template through this code:

```
$processor.processPortlet("71_INSTANCE_xyz1")
```

it shows just the same code in page not any portlet!

After searching, I understand that there is a bug in `TemplateProcessor` class in `portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portlet/layoutconfiguration/util/velocity/TemplateProcessor.java` file

`TemplateProcessor.processPortlet()` ignores supplied portletId.

Can i solve this problem by hook or extension?

If no how can solve problem?

When embedding portlet in template I receive the following error in log:

```
09:23:22,898 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-2][LiferayMethodExceptionEventHandler:33] java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.liferay.portal.model.PortletConstants.getRootPortletId(PortletConstants.java:85)
at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.PortletLocalServiceImpl.getPortletById(PortletLocalServiceImpl.java:403)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor254.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:122)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:211)
at $Proxy65.getPortletById(Unknown Source)
at com.liferay.portal.service.PortletLocalServiceUtil.getPortletById(PortletLocalServiceUtil.java:353)
at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletImpl.processPortlet(RuntimePortletImpl.java:115)
at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletImpl.processPortlet(RuntimePortletImpl.java:203)
at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletImpl.processPortlet(RuntimePortletImpl.java:190)
at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletUtil.processPortlet(RuntimePortletUtil.java:87)
```

Comment: If you need to fix bug in the TemplateProcessor class, you have to use ext plugin, because the mentioned class is in the portal-impl.

Comment: Can you specify what `Template` are you embedding the portlet in? Is it the `portal-normal.vm` in theme or is this a web-content template you are talking about.

Comment: My problem is about web-content template

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me in both Theme (.vm file) and LayoutTemplate (.tpl file)

`$theme.runtime("my_portlet_WAR_myportlet")`

Comment: More on this: https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Embedding+a+portlet+in+the+theme